# Portrait and landscape queries for smartphones, tablets

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I came across this article:

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

It shows various @media queries, which I think are very usefully. But I am slightly confused. It includes things like:

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}
```

And I find it confusing, am I supposed to use 3 of these @media queries or just one that covers landscape and portrait. Can someone explain the difference for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in **first** query you define styles for both portrait and landscape.
in **second** media query you just set styles you want to be applied when smart phone is in landscape mode 
and **last** query is where you're going to enter styles for smart phone where its in portrait mode .
for testing its better to use a **responsive design resizing tool** like http://lab.maltewassermann.com/viewport-resizer/